# Error while attempting to add a user to Active Directory

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I'm now at a loss; I've tried this script several different ways but keep getting an error that says `There is no such object on the server at character 20,2`.

This line reads

```
Set objOU = GetObject("LDAP://ou=users,dc=asp,dc=rippe,dc=com")
```

I get a different error when I change `OU` to `CN` next to users.

The end result desired is to have all of the variables taken from an HTML form and then the script will run to create a new user on our domain.

I haven't even got to the adding the user to groups yet because I can't get past this road block.

```
Dim strID,StrFName,strLName,strFirm,strPwd,strServer,strLMS,strSql,strLMSV

strID = zademo
strFName = Demo
strLName = Tester
strFirm = Demo
strPwd = za1234
strServer = rkasp01
strLMS = y
strSql = y
strLMSV = y
strDisplay = strLName & ", " & strFName


'Create Citrix User Account

If strSql = y OR strLMSV = y Then

    Set objOU = GetObject("LDAP://ou=Users,dc=asp,dc=rippe,dc=com")

    Set objUser = objOU.Create("User", "cn=" & strDisplay)
    objUser.Put "sAMAccountName", strID
    objUser.Put "Description", strFirm

    objUser.Put "givenName", strFName
    objUser.Put "sn", strLName
    objUser.Put "displayName", strDisplay
    objUser.Put "homedirectory", "\\rkpdc\" & strFirm & "\" & strID
    objUser.Put "scriptpath", strFirm & ".bat"
    objUser.SetInfo

End If

objUser.SetPassword strPwd
objUser.Put "PasswordExpired", CLng(1)
objUser.AccountDisabled = FALSE
objUser.SetInfo
```

Answer (score 1):

> Set objOU = GetObject("LDAP://ou=Users,dc=asp,dc=rippe,dc=com")

Usually "Users" is a container, not an OU.

Try:

> Set objOU = GetObject("LDAP://CN=Users,dc=asp,dc=rippe,dc=com")

Comment: What is the new error? AND - If you really need the comma in the user name, you'll need to escape it with a backslash (\\). Otherwise the first name will be considered the next part of the path. I would seriosly advise against using comas in the the user name though! Make your life easier and keep the user name, the first part of the userprincipalname, samaccountname, and mailnickname (if you use exchange) the same!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried and replace example.com with the actual domain.

```
GetObject("LDAP://example.com/OU=Users,DC=asp,DC=rippe,DC=com")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Sorceri, and yes I've removed example.com from the string and replaced it with the actual domain.

Comment: @Patrick Stoddard  Did that resolve the issue? (should have).  if so can you mark it as answered.  If not are you still receiving errors?

Comment: It was never an issue because that was never a part of my code.

Comment: @Patrick Stoddard So when you added it to your code were you then able to connect without receiving the error message that no object exists on the server.  If yes then it did resolve the issue with not being able to connect to the OU/Container.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Dim strUserName
Dim objRootLDAP
Dim objContainer
Dim objNewUser
strUserName = "MorganTestUser"

Set objRootLDAP = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE")

' You can give your own OU like LDAP://OU=TestOU instead of LDAP://CN=Users
Set objContainer = GetObject("LDAP://CN=Users," & _
objRootLDAP.Get("defaultNamingContext")) 

Set objNewUser = objContainer.Create("User", "cn=" & strUserName)
objNewUser.Put "sAMAccountName", strUserName
objNewUser.Put "givenName", "Morgan"
objNewUser.Put "sn", "TestUser"
objNewUser.Put "displayName", "Morgan TestUser"
objNewUser.Put "Description", "AD User created by VB Script"
objNewUser.SetInfo

objNewUser.SetPassword "MyPassword123"
objNewUser.Put "PasswordExpired", CLng(1)
objNewUser.AccountDisabled = FALSE

MsgBox ("New Active Directory User created successfully by using VB Script...")

WScript.Quit
```