# objUser.AccountDisabled = False Not Enabling Account

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

One more question for everyone on this and I am hopefully done with the script

At the line "objUser.AccountDisabled = False" in this script it is supposed to enable the account in Active Directory, however it always creates the accounts disabled. I've tried adding "objUser.SetInfo" after the command and get an error (30, 2) (null): The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist."

Does anyone have any other ideas I can try to get the accounts to be created enabled?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

```
Dim strCode,strID,StrFName,strLName,strFirm,strPwd,strIPGM,strServer,strLMS,strSql,strLMSV,strDisplay

trCode = "za"
strID = "zademo1"
strFName = "Demo"
strLName = "Tester"
strFirm = "Demo"
strPwd = "za1234"
strServer = "rkasp01"
strDisplay = strFName & strLName
strIPGM = "lms" & strCode

Set objOU = GetObject("LDAP://cn=users,dc=asp,dc=rippe,dc=com")

Set objUser = objOU.Create("User", "cn=" & strID)
objUser.Put "sAMAccountName", strID

objUser.Put "givenName", strFName
objUser.Put "sn", strLName
objUser.Put "displayName", strLName
objUser.Put "homedirectory", "\\rkpdc\" & strFirm & "\" & strID
objUser.Put "scriptpath", strFirm & ".bat"
objUser.SetInfo

objUser.SetPassword strPwd
objUser.Put "PasswordExpired", CLng(1)
objUser.AccountDisabled = False  <---------------
'objUser.SetInfo

Set objOU = GetObject("LDAP://cn=users,dc=asp,dc=rippe,dc=com")
Set objGroup = objOU.Create("Group", "cn=" & strFirm)
objGroup.Put "sAMAccountName", strFirm


objGroup.Add objUser.ADSPath
```

Comment: Since you are using CN=Users, I assume my tip helped you.  You might want to accept my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14084702/1027551

Comment: Are you sure this password (za1234) meets your AD password policy? Can you check something more complex instead?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the account to enable by making sure I had run `objUser.SetInfo` to save any changes to the account *before* trying to set the enabled/disabled state.

i.e.

```
objuser.setpassword "swSDD"
OBJUSER.SETINFO
objuser.AccountDisabled=False
```

as opposed to

```
objuser.setpassword "swSDD"
objuser.AccountDisabled=False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the `userAccountControl` attribute on the accounts directly.
The `userAccountControl` attribute is a bitmask, and each bit or flag controls things like account enable/disable status, password requirement, password expired status, [and a whole lot of other stuff, documented here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144).

To enable an account, you need to `XOR` mask the enable/disable flag (hex 0x002) in the existing value, effectively enabling the account if it's disabled. To prevent it from disabling the account if it's enabled, we can check if the account is enabled or not prior.

Example modified script:

```
Dim strCode,strID,StrFName,strLName,strFirm,strPwd,strIPGM,strServer,strLMS,strSql,strLMSV,strDisplay,intUAC

trCode = "za"
strID = "zademo1"
strFName = "Demo"
strLName = "Tester"
strFirm = "Demo"
strPwd = "za1234"
strServer = "rkasp01"
strDisplay = strFName & strLName
strIPGM = "lms" & strCode

Set objOU = GetObject("LDAP://cn=users,dc=asp,dc=rippe,dc=com")

Set objUser = objOU.Create("User", "cn=" & strID)
objUser.Put "sAMAccountName", strID

objUser.Put "givenName", strFName
objUser.Put "sn", strLName
objUser.Put "displayName", strLName
objUser.Put "homedirectory", "\\rkpdc\" & strFirm & "\" & strID
objUser.Put "scriptpath", strFirm & ".bat"

'removed duplicate SetInfo

objUser.SetPassword strPwd
objUser.Put "PasswordExpired", CLng(1)

'get existing value of userAccountControl
intUAC = objUser.Get("userAccountControl")
'AND the current value and the enable/disable flag (0x0002)
If intUAC AND 2 Then
    objUser.Put "userAccountControl", intUAC XOR 2
End If

'set the updated properties
objUser.SetInfo

Set objOU = GetObject("LDAP://cn=users,dc=asp,dc=rippe,dc=com")
Set objGroup = objOU.Create("Group", "cn=" & strFirm)
objGroup.Put "sAMAccountName", strFirm

objGroup.Add objUser.ADSPath
```

Comment: Thanks James, however now I'm getting a type mismatch error on my code when I insert the if then statement. If I leave that statement out it will still create the user disabled but I get that error when I try it inserted.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Try replacing the bitmasking I've used with a manual value that reflects the account status you'd like. For example, remove:
`If intUAC AND 2 Then objUser.Put "userAccountControl", intUAC XOR 2 End If`
 and replace it with 
`objUser.Put "userAccountControl", 544`

That will manually set the account to enabled, and also set it to require a password change on first login. There's a list of values [here](http://www.netvision.com/ad_useraccountcontrol.php)

Comment: Thanks for all the help James, still not getting the accounts created enabled. I'm going to have to check and see if maybe it's Active Directory that's causing the problem.

Comment: No problem. It does seem like something else is disabling the account. Double check that you are creating the user account with a password and password expiry settings that match the domain's password policy (these would be specified in group policy).